# How to read the text element of an XML node without dereferencing entities using XmlReader

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, c#-4.0, xmlreader

I am attempting to read a XML document containing elements like the data mentioned below.

Accessing the text node via `reader.Value`, `reader.ReadContentAsString()`, `reader.ReadContentAsObject()` results in the value read being truncated to the last ampersand, so in the case of the data below that would be ISO^urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referral.  Using `XmlDocument` the text nodes can be read properly so I am assuming there has to be a way to make this work using the reader as well.

```
 <Slot name="urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referenceIdList">
              <ValueList>
                <Value>123456^^^&amp;orgID&amp;ISO^urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referral</Value>
                <Value>098765^^^&amp;orgID&amp;ISO^urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referral</Value>
              </ValueList>
            </Slot>
```

---

**Clarification Edit**

After asking the question I was able to determine my issue came from creating an `XmlReader` from a `XPathNavigator` instance created from a `MessageBuffer` executing in the context of a WCF service call.  Thus @DarkGray's answer was correct for the original question but did not really address the root of the problem.  I provided a second answer which addressed my corner case.

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message; // the inbound SOAP message
var buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(11 * 1024 * 1024);
var navigator = buffer.CreateNavigator();
var reader = navigator.ReadSubtree();
// advance the reader to the text element
//
// `reader.Value` now produces ISO^urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referral
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: `reader.Value`

Output:

```
123456^^^&orgID&ISO^urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referral
098765^^^&orgID&ISO^urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referral
```

Example:

```
public static void Execute()
{
  var xml = @"
    <Slot name='urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referenceIdList'>
      <ValueList>
        <Value>123456^^^&amp;orgID&amp;ISO^urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referral</Value>
        <Value>098765^^^&amp;orgID&amp;ISO^urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referral</Value>
      </ValueList>
    </Slot>
  ";
  var reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(new System.IO.StringReader(xml));
  for (; ; )
  {
    if (!reader.Read())
      break;
    if (reader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.Text)
      Console.WriteLine(reader.Value);
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI, you should not use `new XmlTextReader()` or `new XmlTextWriter()`. They have been deprecated since .NET 2.0. Use `XmlReader.Create()` or `XmlWriter.Create()` instead.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the behavior that I am seeing.  More precisely `reader.value` works when running from within linqpad or MSTest, but it truncates when running in the context of a WCF service call.

Comment: @Tedford Maybe the problem is encoding or not-readable symbols in data? Make simple example with error.

Comment: I was able to find a solution to my problem.  It is a corner case using XmlReader so I will mark this solution as correct for the 99% case and post my solution to account for the niche error.

Answer (score 1):

My question ended up being too broad as the incorrect behavior (truncation when using `reader.Value`) only manifest when the code was executing within the context of a WCF call.  It worked perfectly fine when exercising the logic of the containing class from a unit test.

So the salient setup can be reproduced as follows

**The Failing Code**

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message; // the inbound SOAP message
var buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(11 * 1024 * 1024);
var navigator = buffer.CreateNavigator();
var reader = navigator.ReadSubtree();
// advance the reader to the text element
//
// `reader.Value` now produces ISO^urn:ihe:iti:xds:2013:referral
```

Once this reader instance was created then any XmlText node read from it produced the truncated value when the text contained an character entity reference.  The only way I found that allow for the original value to be read in high-fidelity was to eschew the use of the XPathNavigator completely and instead take the hit of creating another `Message` instance.  Note, the fix uses the long way around to write the SOAP envelope to the stream as affected service is using MTOM encoding.  Writing to the stream directly from the MessageBuffer resulted in the MIME fences being written out.

**The Fix**

```
System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message message; // the inbound SOAP
var buffer = message.CreateBufferedCopy(MaxMessageSize);
var message = buffer.CreateMessage();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream))
{
    message.WriteMessage(writer);
    writer.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;

    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
    {
        // business logic goes here
    }
}
```